# Unexpected value 'DataTableModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

I want to perform crud operations on angular datatable,when I am trying to use https://stacktrender.com/post/st/simplest-angular-4-crud-example-with-bootstrap-4-datatable. the  error is Unexpected value 'DataTableModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: can you share your app.module.ts file ?

Comment: The component where you used to implement this task should be declared in the same module where you import DataTableModule.

Comment: please post your app module code

Answer (score 0):

I think you did some mistake to implement. It seems you have missed to import DataTableModule in appmodule.ts file. Check this link if you have difficulties then https://github.com/mohittanwani/angular4-crud-example